Why are NSolve and Solve not working for ArcTan?
The following is my code.
Wu = 2 Pi * (400 * 10^6);
ro7 = 1/(0.2*0.6*10^3);
ro5 = 1/(0.1*0.6*10^3);
Ro2 = ro7*ro5/(ro7 + ro5);
C2 = 1.35*10^(-12);
Wp2 = 1 / (Ro2*C2);
Solve[3 Pi /4 == ArcTan[Wu/Wp1] + ArcTan[Wu/Wp2], Wp1]
NSolve[3 Pi /4 == ArcTan[Wu/Wp1] + ArcTan[Wu/Wp2], Wp1, Reals]

This will generate empty {}

3Pi/4 is outside the range of the right-hand side of your equation.

Subtract Pi and you get a solution: Solve[- Pi/4 == ArcTan[Wu/Wp1] + ArcTan[Wu/Wp2], Wp1]

Amplifying on @MichaelE2's comment
$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Wu = 2 Pi*(400*10^6);
ro7 = 1/(0.2*0.6*10^3);
ro5 = 1/(0.1*0.6*10^3);
Ro2 = ro7*ro5/(ro7 + ro5);
C2 = 1.35*10^(-12);
Wp2 = 1/(Ro2*C2);

Plot[ArcTan[Wu/Wp1] + ArcTan[Wu/Wp2],
 {Wp1, -10^12, 10^12},
 PlotRange -> {-2, 2},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 ScalingFunctions -> {"SignedLog", None},
 GridLines -> {None, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]


EDIT: Using exact values to refine the function interval
Wu = 2 Pi*(400*10^6);
ro7 = 1/(0.2*0.6*10^3) // Rationalize;
ro5 = 1/(0.1*0.6*10^3) // Rationalize;
Ro2 = ro7*ro5/(ro7 + ro5);
C2 = 1.35*10^(-12) // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
Wp2 = 1/(Ro2*C2);

f[Wp1_] := ArcTan[Wu/Wp1] + ArcTan[Wu/Wp2]

Limit[f[Wp1], Wp1 -> #] & /@ {-Infinity, Infinity}

(* {ArcTan[(3 π)/500000], ArcTan[(3 π)/500000]} *)

% // N

(* {0.0000188496, 0.0000188496} *)

The function interval is
Limit[f[Wp1], Wp1 -> 0, Direction -> #] & /@ {"FromBelow", "FromAbove"}

(* {-(π/2) + ArcTan[(3 π)/500000], π/2 + ArcTan[(3 π)/500000]} *)

